# Restrict user to only entering one word in UITextField

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

Is there a way to only allow the user enter one word in the `UITextField`? If so, how?

Here's the current code that I'm using:

```
-(BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

_disallowedCharacters = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet];

for(int i = 0; i < [_searchBox.text length]; i++){
    unichar c = [_searchBox.text characterAtIndex:i];
    if (![_disallowedCharacters characterIsMember:c])
    {
        return NO;
    }
}
return YES;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "one word"? In some languages, space isn’t a word separator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol:

```
- (BOOL) textField:(UITextField*)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString*)textEntered
{
    for (int i = 0; i < [textEntered length]; i++)
    {
        unichar c = [textEntered characterAtIndex:i];
        if ([disallowedCharacters characterIsMember:c])
        {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

where `disallowedCharacters` is an `NSCharacterSet` containing the characters that should not be accepted by the keyboard, i.e. a space, punctuation, numbers, etc:

```
self.disallowedCharacters = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" ,.123"];
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I define this characterSet?

Comment: @cfarm54: See the second code sample I posted. Declare an instance variable in your header file to match it; `@property` and `@synthesize` it and then define it in `viewDidLoad` or something.

Comment: @Evan interesting. This code is only allowing me to type one letter. I'd like to be able to only type one word.

Comment: You can try `+ (id)whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet` on NSCharacterSet to get whitespace characters. Checking against whitespace should limit you to one word.

Comment: If your definition of a word is more strict than just non-whitespace, you can create a `mutableCopy` of the whitespace set to add other disallowed characters to it.

Comment: @kevboh could you put this in a different answer with some example code?

Comment: @cfarm54: I modified the code sample. The return values were swapped.

Answer (score 2):

For a character set (for Evan's answer) that checks against whitespace and newlines, you can use

```
self.disallowedCharacters = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
```

If you want to check against characters besides whitespace and newlines, create a `mutableCopy` and add whatever you'd like to it:

```
NSMutableCharacterSet *set = [[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet] mutableCopy];
[set formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet punctuationCharacterSet]];
[set formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet symbolCharacterSet];
[set addCharactersInString:@"whatever you want"];
...
self.disallowedCharacters = [[set copy] autorelease];
[set release];
```

The [NSCharacterSet docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) have a good overview of the character sets available to you.

Comment: this seems like it should work but I'm still only able to type one letter before it stops letting me type. any clue to why this would happen?

Comment: see evan's comment, your return values are swapped.